# Add an element to ArrayList when there is no space left

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to understand **add** operation of **ArrayList** Class in Java from [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/ArrayList.java.html). Here is a portion of code:

```
//Proprties:

  107       /**
  108        * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
  109        * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer.
  110        */
  111       private transient Object[] elementData;
  112   
  113       /**
  114        * The size of the ArrayList (the number of elements it contains).
  115        *
  116        * @serial
  117        */
  118       private int size;


  404       /**
  405        * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
  406        *
  407        * @param e element to be appended to this list
  408        * @return <tt>true</tt> (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
  409        */
  410       public boolean add(E e) {
  411           ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
  412           elementData[size++] = e;
  413           return true;
  414       }

  183       private void ensureCapacityInternal(int minCapacity) {
  184           modCount++;
  185           // overflow-conscious code
  186           if (minCapacity - elementData.length > 0)
  187               grow(minCapacity);
  188       }

  198       /**
  199        * Increases the capacity to ensure that it can hold at least the
  200        * number of elements specified by the minimum capacity argument.
  201        *
  202        * @param minCapacity the desired minimum capacity
  203        */
  204       private void grow(int minCapacity) {
  205           // overflow-conscious code
  206           int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
  207           int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1);
  208           if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)
  209               newCapacity = minCapacity;
  210           if (newCapacity - MAX_ARRAY_SIZE > 0)
  211               newCapacity = hugeCapacity(minCapacity);
  212           // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
  213           elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
  214       }
```

Steps for the elements insertion are: verify if it does exist enough space before inserting a new element by calling ***ensureCapacityInternal*** , in case there is no enough space we call ***grow*** operation to increase elementData capacity.

My problem is that I can't see a case where **newCapacity - minCapacity < 0** condition in **grow** operation will satisfied.

Can you explain to me the utility of this condition or give an example where this condition would be satisfied?

Comment: This was already asked here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33147339/difference-between-if-a-b-0-and-if-a-b

Comment: @Eran Yes it's the same question asked in another way. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My problem is that I can't see a case where newCapacity - minCapacity
>   < 0 condition in grow operation will satisfied.
>
> Can you explain to me the utility of this condition or give an example
>   where this condition would be satisfied?

What about the case when integer overflow occurs? This is the best case, which depicts that ArrayList cannot grow any further.

Comment: @You're right that's why the comments // overflow-conscious code exist. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The case when `minCapacity` is bigger than `newCapacity` is not in the case of `add` but when you use the `addAll` method. There you can provide a `Collection` of elements which can be for example 100 new Objects to insert onto your empty `ArrayList`. In this case the default capacity of `10` will be used to calculate the new capacity:

```
int newCapacity = oldCapacity + (oldCapacity >> 1); (10 + 5 = 15)
```

In this case `15` is not enough to store `100` elements. In this case `if (newCapacity - minCapacity < 0)` is evaluated to `true`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. You're right . But in my case it's integer overflow problem